# How can I show value in the textarea from the database /based on the selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, scriptlet

I need to view the another column `<%=rs1.getString(2)%>` depending on the select value.
I need to show that value in the text area.
How can I implement this?
-> [pastebin.com/ewSB7KS6](https://pastebin.com/ewSB7KS6)

```
<label for="issue_id"><strong>Select Issue:</strong></label>
<select name="issue_id" id="issue_id" required>
<option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select</option>
<%
while(rs1.next()){ 
%>
<option value="<%=rs1.getString(1)%>"> <%=rs1.getString(1) %> <%=rs1.getString(2) %></option>
<% } %>
</select> 
<label for="minfeed"><strong>Feed:</strong></label>
<textarea id="minfeed" rows="4" cols="50" name="minfeed" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onchange` event of jquery to get selected value and then put that selected value to textarea using `.text()` .Demo code :

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  //getting value from select
  var select = $(this).val();
  //splitting both value 
  var v = select.split(",");
  //getting second value after ,
  $("#minfeed").text(v[1]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="issue_id"><strong>Select Issue:</strong></label>
<select name="issue_id" id="issue_id" required>
  <option class="placeholder" selected disabled value="">Select</option>
  <%
while(rs1.next()){ 
%>
    <!--here i have added both value in one with seprator ","-->
    <option value="<%=rs1.getString(1)%> ,<%=rs1.getString(2) %>">
      <%=rs1.getString(1) %>
        <%=rs1.getString(2) %>
    </option>
    <% } %>
</select>
<label for="minfeed"><strong>Feed:</strong></label>
<textarea id="minfeed" rows="4" cols="50" name="minfeed" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Update 1: As i have already commented you can acheieve that by using ajax .So, your jquery code will look like below :

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  //getting value from select
  var select = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'yourservleturl',
        data:'select ='+select , //<--passing value to servlet
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
       $("#minfeed").text(data);
        }
    }); 

});
```

Now ,get value of that `select` in servlet using `request.getParameter("select");` in `doPost` method and then passed this value to your query for selecting required `feed` .Lastly, use `response.getWriter().write("your feed");` to send value back to ajax and show in textarea.

Comment: Actually this wont change if you are connected to a database. rs1.getString(2) means I am fetching a value from database for a particular column. And in the textarea I need to display the value corresponding to the selected row.

Comment: This will help you understand.

Comment: this will work because you are fetching all value because option will have <option value="rs1 ,rs2"/> where rs2 is feed of the same id ? did you tried above code what does work ?

Comment: second option would be using ajax for the same , get the value of selected id passing in ajax to servlet/jsp sending back response and assigning same to textarea

Comment: U have taken option value as both rs1 and rs2. The option value would be only rs1 and I need to display rs2 so thats why I told u this isnt working. I need the option value for other instances. Thats why cant take both rs1 and rs2.

Comment: i have updated my code.. check and see if that works for you .